# How to fix mysql connectivity issues on bosh-lite for a cf.org sample spring boot app?

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I am trying to `cf push` this code from [this](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/pong_matcher_spring) github repo after running `mvn package`, but I get a failed app deployment.

I have created a user defined service for ***mysql*** since ***cleardb*** is not available on my bosh-lite local vm. I created the mysql service and named it as 'mysql' as well as guided by [this](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/user-provided.html).

The `application.yml` in this spring boot app points to localhost. That doesn't work even for a local (non cf) build without corrrecting the jdbc url. [Here](http://pastebin.com/uq5MJEnq) is the stack trace from the bosh-lite vm when I try to `cf push` this app and read the logs using `cf logs springpong --recent`.

Also, why do we need both, the `manifest.yml` and the `application.yml` providing database details ?

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ cat pong_matcher_spring/src/main/resources/application.yml
---
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/pong_matcher_spring_development
    username: springpong
    password: springpong
  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: none
    show_sql: false
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ cat pong_matcher_spring/manifest.yml
---
applications:
  - name: springpong
    buildpack: java_buildpack
    path: target/pong-matcher-spring-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
    services:
      - mysql
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$
```

Can someone help me fix this ? 
TIA

Comment: If you have specified the connection information in the user-defined service, you don't need to put it into the application.yml. Try using this format for the jdbcUrl property in your user-defined service: mysql://localhost/pong_matcher_spring_development:3306

Comment: The user defined service (cups) was created using this command -> http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/user-provided.html#create. AFAIK it needs a host, port, dbname, username and password. I don't get to provide a url to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening as the `security groups` were not setup to allow for network access. A sample gist of commands can be seen here -> https://gist.github.com/menicosia/2e9c414430138064f945

Caveat: This is ***only*** for bosh-lite and development purposes.